# Add a newline after each terminal command except at the beginning

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal, newlines

I want to add a newline after every command I enter in the terminal. Right now, I have this line in my `.bash_profile` file:

```
export PS1="\n\u$ "
```

This works as expected:

[image]

However the issue with this method is that there will be a newline created at the top when the terminal starts. Is there a way to stop a newline from coming when starting the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit heavy but you can use this in your .bash_profile:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='PROMPT_COMMAND='\''PS1="\n\u$ "'\'
```

PROMPT_COMMAND is evaluated before every prompt. On the first line it resets itself to set the PS1 prompt for the next time (and continually thereafter).
The `'\''` bit is to include a `'` inside a single-quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

One approach using printf :

```
$ printf '%s\n' * $'\n'
```

or better (for every commands)  :

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND="echo"
$ ls
```